# Active Directory authentication in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm working on a Rails 2 app (I know it's pretty old), but that's what they are working on. I need a working approach to use AD authentication in the app.

Seems like I could do it with 'devise_ldap_authenticatable' gem, but they aren't using Devise for authentication.

Comment: Googled it for you: http://erniemiller.org/2008/04/04/simplified-active-directory-authentication/ http://erik.debill.org/2010/05/22/activedirectory-integration-for-ruby-apps http://activedirectory.rubyforge.org/
https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+active+directory+authentication

Comment: In which company you work in Bangalore.. Me also in B'lore .. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a much simpler method using this gem (https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap), and a great tutorial is here: http://net-ldap.rubyforge.org/Net/LDAP.html

Answer (score 1):

OneLogin have a ['ruby toolkit'](https://onelogin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201175674-SAML-toolkit-for-Ruby-on-Rails) that we used to add SAML authentication handling to our app for Active Directory. No obligation to use their services. Might be a starting point at least for you!